# How to read and search the content from .asp file using C#.net code

Tags: c#, html, xaml

I have some .asp files and I want to read the content file like we did for xmldocument.

For an example:-
suppose my .asp file contents following code:-

```html
  <DIV id=DIV_CI_0084 class="Horiz_Small" style="LEFT: 677px; TOP: 361px; 
    position:absolute">0084</DIV>

   <DIV id=DIV_BF_0202 class="Horiz_Small" style="LEFT: 393px; TOP: 313px; 
   position:absolute">202</DIV>
   <DIV id=DIV_SHO_0202 class="Horiz_Small" style="LEFT: 715px; TOP: 296px; 
   position:absolute">SHO 0202</DIV>
   <DIV id=DIV_HCO_202 class="Horiz_Small" style="LEFT: 657px; TOP: 300px; 
   position:absolute">HCO 202</DIV>
  <DIV id=DIV_BF_0203 class="Horiz_Small" style="LEFT: 769px; TOP: 313px; 
  position:absolute">203</DIV>
  <DIV id=DIV_BF_0204 class="Horiz_Small" style="LEFT: 828px; TOP: 313px; 
  position:absolute">204</DIV>
  <DIV id=DIV_BF_0205 class="Horiz_Small" style="LEFT: 882px; TOP: 313px; 
  position:absolute">205</DIV>
  <DIV id=DIV_BF_0206 class="Horiz_Small" style="LEFT: 971px; TOP: 319px; 
  position:absolute">206</DIV>
  <DIV id=DIV_BF_0207 class="Horiz_Small" style="LEFT: 1075px; TOP: 314px; 
  position:absolute">207</DIV>
  <DIV id=DIV_BF_0208 class="Horiz_Small" style="LEFT: 1144px; TOP: 312px; 
  position:absolute">208</DIV>
  <DIV id=DIV_BF_0209 class="Horiz_Small" style="LEFT: 1147px; TOP: 255px; 
  position:absolute">209</DIV>
  <DIV id=DIV_BF_0210 class="Horiz_Small" style="LEFT: 1147px; TOP: 154px; 
  position:absolute">210</DIV>
```

Now I want to read node id=DIV_BF_0208 and extract the data style and position.

If we have xaml file then we can use concept of child node, attribute concept.

Do we have similar concept or covert it into excel file then read it.

I need that to develop some tool using c#.net

Comment: I've removed the ASP.NET tag because this question isn't related to ASP.NET.

Comment: If you're not wanting to actually execute the VBScript in the .asp file and you just want to read the HTML content, then it shouldn't be different to accessing any other file. That has been covered many times over on this site. Look at HtmlAgilityPack, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My strategy would be to fix it, lingering 20yr old asp files in your solution isn't going to look very modern. Instead put all the entries in a Database, even a NoSQL dB.

<sub>I'm guessing this asp site is not online anymore and you have a finite set of asp files to scan (if not `wget` the website).</sub>

Extract INSERT SQL Statements from raw asp files using HtmlAgilityPack:

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

foreach(HtmlNode div in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'Horiz_Small')]"))
{
  sb.Append("INSERT INTO Table (Cols) VALUES ");
  sb.AppendLine(div.InnerText);
}
File.WriteAllText("C:\\Path\\inserts1.sql", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks.....I like your solution and let me try with this...I will comeback to you